# Undefined step reference in PhpStorm when using Codeception and Gherkin

Tags: php, phpstorm, codeception, behat, gherkin

I'd like to be able to use PhpStorm's "Go To Declaration" feature (*Command + B* on a Mac) in Gherkin feature files when using Codeception. However, PhpStorm doesn't seem to figure out where the steps are defined, and outputs this warning:

> Undefined step reference: […] [image: Warning screenshot]

When I'm using Behat, PhpStorm understands where the steps are defined.

## Steps to reproduce

1. `mkdir codeception`
2. `cd codeception`
3. `composer require "codeception/codeception" --dev`
4. `./vendor/bin/codecept bootstrap`
5. `./vendor/bin/codecept generate:feature acceptance first`
6. Open the project directory in PhpStorm.
7. Make sure that PhpStorm knows that Codeception is installed: [image: Codeception PhpStorm configuration]
8. Make sure that the PhpStorm plugins *Gherkin* and *Codeception Framework* are installed.
9. Add a step to `tests/acceptance/first.feature`.
10. `./vendor/bin/codecept gherkin:snippets acceptance`

This results in the following code. (Not everything is included – let me know if I need to add anything.)

`tests/acceptance/first.feature`:

```
Feature: first
  In order to ...
  As a ...
  I need to ...

  Scenario: try first
    When I visit "/"
```

`tests/_support/AcceptanceTester.php`:

```
<?php

/**
 * Inherited Methods
 * @method void wantToTest($text)
 * @method void wantTo($text)
 * @method void execute($callable)
 * @method void expectTo($prediction)
 * @method void expect($prediction)
 * @method void amGoingTo($argumentation)
 * @method void am($role)
 * @method void lookForwardTo($achieveValue)
 * @method void comment($description)
 * @method \Codeception\Lib\Friend haveFriend($name, $actorClass = NULL)
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD)
*/
class AcceptanceTester extends \Codeception\Actor
{
    use _generated\AcceptanceTesterActions;

   /**
    * Define custom actions here
    */

    /**
     * @When I visit :arg1
     */
    public function iVisit($arg1)
    {
        throw new \Codeception\Exception\Incomplete("Step `I visit :arg1` is not defined");
    }
}
```

However, PhpStorm doesn't know where `iVisit()` is. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently PhpStorm seems to use the Behat Context interface to determine which classes define implementations for the Gherkin steps in **.feature** files, so a workaround to have PhpStorm find the steps in the codeception tester is to add the `Behat\Behat\Context\Context` interface somewhere in your source tree

```
/* Context.php */
namespace Behat\Behat\Context;

interface Context { }
```

and then have the `AcceptanceTester` implement that interface (which is an empty marker interface)

```
class AcceptanceTester extends \Codeception\Actor implements Context ...
```

Comment: That's great, thanks a lot. I would have never thought of that (and still don't understand why it works).

Answer (score 6):

Not supported yet, please vote:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-34963

Answer (score 2):

Building off [Roverwolf's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46064672/1713620) answer.

Add this to the top of the AcceptanceTester file.

```
namespace Behat\Behat\Context { 
   interface Context { } 
}
```

Then have AcceptanceTester implement that.  Wrapping namespaces like this is a common trick in PHP testing to fake methods that exist in other namespaces.

```
namespace {
    class AcceptanceTester extends \Codeception\Actor implements \Behat\Behat\Context\Context
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another step definition file, and I use Behat's Context. Then implements Context in the class declaration.

```
use Behat\Behat\Context;

class myClassSteps implements Context\Context
{
     step definitions
}
```

It works for me.